# Performing joins for a 1-to-N mapping

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have these models:

```
Student:
    string name
    list<Subject> enrolledCourses

Subject:
    string name
    integer credits
```

The way I can store this in a database is:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    student_subject_mapping int NOT NULL,
    name character varying
);

CREATE TABLE student_subject_mapping(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id int,
    subject_id int
);

CREATE TABLE subject(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying,
    credits int
);
```

To fetch a student (pseudo-code), I can either do this:

```
var student = SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?id;
var subjects = SELECT * FROM subject WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM student_subject_mapping WHERE student_id = ?student['id']);

make_student(student, subjects)
```

Or, I can do this:

```
var student = SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN student_subject_mapping
                  ON student.id = student_subject_mapping.student_id INNER JOIN subject
                  ON subject.id = student_subject_mapping.subject_id;
```

The above will return rows of the type (omitting some columns for brevity):

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| student.name | subject.name      |
+--------------+-------------------+
| Rohan        | Physics           |
| Rohan        | Biology           |
| Rohan        | Computer Science  |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

In this case, I can fetch the information for the `student` part from any of the rows, and the subjects by iterating over the other rows. This might sound a bit complicated, but it is really simple for me since I use jooq:

```
Result<Record> rows = query.execute();
if (rows.size() > 0) {
    StudentRecord student = rows.get(0).into(Tables.STUDENT);
}

List<SubjectRecord> subjects = rows.stream()
                                   .map(x -> x.into(Tables.SUBJECT))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it. Things get more complicated, if `subject` was something like:

```
Subject:
    string name
    list<Department> offeringDepartments
```

I know this is a bad example since `subject` should probably not be storing info about the offering departments, but please play along, as I am sure you can see where models might have multiple levels of nesting. In that case not only do my queries get complicated, I have rows of the type:

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
| student.name | subject.name      | departments.name |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
| Rohan        | Physics           | Science          |
| Rohan        | Biology           | Science          |
| Rohan        | Computer Science  | EECS             |
| Rohan        | Computer Science  | IT               |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

In the previous case, I could get info about `student` from the first row itself, but I have no way to know that the boundaries for getting information about the subject row is [0, 1]; [1, 2] and [2, 4] (other than probably some extra SQL magic).

So, which method would you recommend I follow? Or is there a third better alternative to this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you bother with those details by hand? Your JPA implementation of choice (like Hibernate) could hide all the complexity from you, requiring only the mapping on the model you mentioned.

Comment: @Deltharis: maybe rohan doesn't like obfuscating the database layer.

Comment: Pretty much what @a_horse_with_no_name said. We used to use Hibernate, but switching to jooq which does not abstract away SQL has made us a lot more productive and our debugging time has gone down significantly. We pretty much never have to debug issues in the data layer, while with Hibernate we pretty much had to do it any time things became a bit complex. Also, since we are in complete control of the SQL, at a lot of places our software has become a lot more performant.

Comment: we made the same experience after switching to QueryDSL.

Answer (score 0):

I think that retrieving both student and subject in a single query is entirely appropriate. Some frameworks (ActiveRecord) will indeed make it very easy to work like this. The use case is generally where you are selecting from a table and a bunch of "parent" tables, but there's nothing wrong with doing it for a single child relationship.

Where it would get tricky is with multiple child relationships, for example if you were retrieving product, and its associated child orders and inventory levels, where 100 orders and 10 inventory levels equals 1,000 rows with much redundant data (what is called in some circles a "chasm trap"). In that case you'd want to use two or possibly three queries to return the results.